# Error with Cloudflare on auto login with Python

Tags: python, selenium, cloudflare

I am doing a simple project where I want to login to a page, for this I use Python with Selenium.

This is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from getpass import getpass

username = input("Enter your user name: ")
password = getpass("Enter your password: ")

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\stbaz\\Documents\\Python\\ChromeTools\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.innvictus.com/login")

username_textbox = driver.find_element_by_id("j_username")
username_textbox.send_keys(username)

password_textbox = driver.find_element_by_id("j_password")
password_textbox.send_keys(password)

login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/form[1]/div[5]/button")
login_button.submit()
```

Everything works very well, but when the submit button is activated, the page freezes, I try to refresh and the following error appears
[image]

The site works with Cloudflare, am I missing something to make it work correctly?
Thank you for your support

Answer (score 0):

It already works correctly adding the following lines before indicating the path of the executable file

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\stbaz\\Documents\\Python\\ChromeTools\\chromedriver.exe", options=options)
```